# PopUp Video Player

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to play video in dialog with fixed width and height. I played video but some video content display outside of dialog and some video content display top right corner of dialog.
I try to set width and height at runtime but it does not work.

Following is code

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_video_popup);

    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    //String path ="http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp";
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mVideoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(300, 400);
    dialog.show();
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: can you show us your codes ?

Comment: i fixed this,There is emulator problem It works on device

Answer (score 0):

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout((int) (window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() * .90),
        (int) (window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() * .90));
```